# There a quicker way between Ubuntu and my android to send files instead of Bluetooth or cable

Tags: bluetooth, files, android, sharing, wifi-direct

Is There a quicker way between Ubuntu and my android to send files instead of Bluetooth or usb cable? Am I aware of quick share that uses wifi. can this be done? I'm using a Samsung galaxy note 10. I'm not sure if this has been asked before.

Comment: I guess the easiest is KDE CONNECT as mentioned by @codlord But it will not give as much speed as USB cable will gives you ;))

Answer (score 2):

I use [SSH/SFTP Server - Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xnano.android.sshserver&hl=en_CA&gl=US) from Banana Studio.

It has advantages:

- No USB cables which can be a pain to find at times.
- No teethering your phone to your comptuer or USB hub.
- No bluetooth which many seem to have problems with.
- KDE Connect requires installing application on phone and in Ubuntu.
- SSH client is already installed in Ubuntu.
- Logon with SSH which provides automatic encryption.
- Use SSHFS to mount phone as "normal" partition.
- Automate file transfers with bash scripts.
- Utilize Nautilus (Files) for browsing directories on phone.

Having the phone as an SSH server is faster for me to use but I'm not sure if file transfer over WiFi is faster than over USB cable or bluetooth. A lot would depend on the WiFi speed of your phone and router.

Answer (score 2):

Install `kdeconnect` on your phone...

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp

Install `gsconnect` on your computer...

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/

Pair them. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Try [KDE Connect](https://kdeconnect.kde.org/) it's installable from Ubuntu software store or command-line apt (and of course the KDE Connect app from Android store).

I just use it for ocassional file transfers but it has loads of other features if you want/need them.

Answer (score 1):

Use Total Commander with WLAN-Plugin on the phone. Total Commander can share files via Wifi that you download via Browser or connect via sftp

I assume both devices are in the same WLAN.

Answer (score 0):

Through cable, you can use the Android File Transfer for Linux, available from snap store:

```
sudo snap install android-file-transfer-linux
```

[Android File Transfer for Linux - MTP](https://snapcraft.io/install/android-file-transfer-linux/ubuntu)